# Laplace transform of integral

Tags: laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace Transform of:
>
> $\int_{0}^{t} \frac{Y(u)}{\sqrt{t-u}}du$

I understand that $\mathcal{L}\{\int_{0}^{t} Y(u) \ du\} = \frac{y(s)}{s}$,  but I don't understand how this works when other variables are involved (in this case how do we handle the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-u}}$ term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with semi-primitives, nice! Well, the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{Y(u)}{\sqrt{t-u}}\,du $$
is the convolution between $Y(u)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$, so its Laplace transform is simply the product between $(\mathcal{L}Y)(s)$ and
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\right)(s)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s}}. $$
This is related to fractional calculus since a possible (but not very common) definition of a semi-primitive is
$$ (D^{-1/2} f)(x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\cdot(\mathcal{L} f)(s)\right](x).$$
In these terms
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{Y(u)}{\sqrt{t-u}}\,du = \sqrt{\pi}\,(D^{-1/2} Y)(t).$$
 <sup>It is interesting to check what happens by taking $Y$ as a Legendre or Chebyshev polynomial/function, but I do not want to spoil too much of my future work.</sup>

Comment: Of course, how could I have forgotten about convolutions! Thanks, mate.

Comment: @Dr.Doofus: you're very welcome.